# Not able to understand the meaning of question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

> car moving with a speed of 40 km / h can be stopped by applying brakes after at least 2 m. If the same car is moving with a speed of 80 km / h, what is the minimum stopping distance

Does this mean that after 2 m, You will apply brakes and then it stops. What is the retardation value  with which you are brakes.I am not understand the meaning of the values.

Comment: I think the question means that, at 40 km/h, the car can be stopped in 2 m. What is the required distance at 80 km/h? But you are correct, it is badly worded.

Comment: Why does it need to apply brakes after 2m.

Comment: I even think so @hdhondt

Comment: Why do we need this relation to find after how much time will the other car apply brakes.

Comment: What I meant was "after the brakes are applied, it takes 2 m to stop the car, when it is moving at 40 km/h"

Comment: How can it mean that ?

Comment: @hdhondt it says after at least 2m.So it takes 2m for for the time to apply brakes.After that they apply brakes right.

Comment: If you read it that way, it is impossible to answer the question. That's why I said it is badly worded, and why I'm assuming my interpretation of "the car travels 2 m while braking".

Comment: Ok.I don’t understand why is it badly worded.It is a famous question in exams actually.@hdhondt Thank you still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going 40 kph in a vehicle, you apply full brakes and come to a stop in 2 meters. With this same vehicle and braking ability, what distance will the vehicle travel after you apply full brakes at 80 kph?